# How can I use a halign in a macro definition?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I tried this:

```tex
\def\Anschrift#1#2#3#4#5#6{\vbox to27.3mm{
  \rmx\baselineskip=13pt
  \vfill
  \halign to8cm{#\hfil\cr
    #1\cr
    #2\cr
    #3\cr
    #4\cr
    #5\cr
    #6\cr}%
  \vfill
  \vss}\nointerlineskip
\vskip8.46mm}

\Anschrift{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}

\bye
```

But I get the the error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Anschrift.
```

How can I escape the `#`?

Comment: Just double the `#` for the alignment token (so `\halign to8cm{##\hfil\cr...`).

Comment: Unrelated, but you should set `\tabskip`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just double the `#` to get a single `#` inside a macro definition.

So for your example, use the following:

```
\def\Anschrift#1#2#3#4#5#6{\vbox to27.3mm{
  \baselineskip=13pt
  \vfill
  \halign to8cm{##\hfil\cr
    #1\cr
    #2\cr
    #3\cr
    #4\cr
    #5\cr
    #6\cr}%
  \vfill
  \vss}\nointerlineskip
\vskip8.46mm}

\Anschrift{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}

\bye
```

(I removed the `\rmx` from the definition, because you didn't include its definition in your MWE, and I'm lazy)

Comment: `rmx` is just my `tenrm`. I like roman numerals. I have also `rmvii` and so on...

Comment: @ceving guessed as much, but "I'm lazy" :P

Answer (score 5):

As was said elsewhere, you need to use `##` instead `#` in your `\halign`.

But your code is somewhat curious:

You don't need `\halign to 8cm` because the 8cm dimension cannot be visible, because you create a `\vbox` which is supposed in vertical mode (because of `\nointerlineskip` followed after the `\vbox` which cannot be used in horizontal mode).

If you replace `\halign to 8cm` only by `\halign` (without the width specification) then no visible changes is done, only the warning about underfull \hbox in alignment will be removed.

Moreover, you don't need `\halign` at all because your `\halign` sets only single left aligned colum, which can be done by a paragraph with `\hfil\break` in it:

```
\def\Anschrift#1#2#3#4#5#6{\vbox to27.3mm{
  \baselineskip=13pt
  \vfill
  \def\\{\hfil\break}
    \noindent #1\\
    #2\\
    #3\\
    #4\\
    #5\\
    #6
  \vfill
  \vss}\nointerlineskip
\vskip8.46mm}
```

Comment: One could as well stack `\hbox`es inside the `\vbox` and `\vfill\vss` seems redundant as well.

Comment: My intention was to define a clipping box needed for the [address window of a DIN letter (Anschriftzone)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_5008#/media/Datei:DIN_5008_Form_B.svg). It must not be wider than 8cm.

Comment: @ceving in that case I'd set the `\hsize` of your `\vbox` and use the `\hfil\break` definition of this answer. Also, I'd drop `\vss` to get a warning for an overful vbox.